# Calculate (d * b) when (G, *) is a group with a partial table for * given.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've been working on the following problem: Suppose G = {1,a,b,c,d,e}, and (G, *) is a group with the partial table for * given by:

[image]

I need to calculate d * b. The trick, I've been told, is that I don't need to complete the partial table at all; rather, I can just concentrate on the four properties necessary (and sufficient) for the pair (G, *) to be a group. Those would be closure, associativity, identity, and inverses.

And so the first thing I did was change d to (a * c), as it shows in the chart. So we get:

(a * c) * b

But I can't quite figure out where to go next. Could I perhaps get some help in figuring out d * b?

Comment: (a × c) × b = a × (c × b). Why use parentheses at all when your elements are associative?

Comment: (bxd) = ((axc)xb) = ((a)x(cxb)) = (axd) = e